# How can I use variable while getting accessed ODBC with R?

Tags: r

I just finished getting data via `ODBC` using query sentences.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", 
classPath="C:/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar")
con <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@111.111.1.111:1111:FS05","11111","11111")
query <- "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%D3771%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' 
AND END_YMD = '99999999'"

result <- dbGetQuery(con,query)
head(result)
```

Using this sentences It is possible to take all the data which I want.
But I want to generalize this code

I mean, even when I don't know the expression like 'D3771' I want to make this general something.
For instances, the expression randomly decided like A2942, B5828, C1294 ... sth..
then I want to get the information using this random outcome so I save this random expression in the variable 'box'

so I want to make query like that
 "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE ***'%box%'*** AND TYPE_GB ='A2' 
    AND END_YMD = '99999999'"

Again,
In the end I don't need to insert A2942, B5828, C1294 directly in the query. just random expression saved in the variable 'box' then using for loop expression in the box changed automatically and applied to query to get the appropriate outcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I mean is pass the variable to the query statement. It seems like, If there is dice, then we get random number 1 to 6. So I want this random number in the space 'D3771'. The outcome is random number inserted this space automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the static parts of your query in an object

```
query <- "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%random_box%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
```

Randomly generate a letter and number combination

```
letters    <- c("A", "B", "C")
random_box <- paste0(sample(letters, 1),round(runif(0,9999, n = 1)))
```

Substitute this into your query

```
new.query <- gsub("random_box", random_box, query)
```

Now `new.query` has a value like

> [1] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%B5647%'
>   AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"

You can set the `min` and `max` values of the number in `runif`. If it is necessary to have a certain number of digits you can also "pad" the numbers with 0, so that if your random number is small, like 12, then you would get 0012 instead of just 12.

To scale this up you could either run a simple look or loop or just increase the `n` of `sample` and/or `runif` to whatever size you would like then either create many copies of the statement from those results *or* change the SQL statement to include the keyword "OR" between each result so that you only have to run 1 SQL statement.

For example, instead of getting 1 new result, if you wanted 10 then you could just do something like this:

```
random_box <- paste0(sample(letters, 2),round(runif(0,9999, n = 10)))
length(random_box) # [1] 10

all        <- sapply(random_box, function(random_box) gsub("random_box", random_box, query))
names(all) <- NULL

all
```

> ```
>  [1] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C1866%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [2] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%A3236%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [3] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C8977%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [4] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%A735%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'" 
>  [5] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C2102%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [6] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%A3169%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [7] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C2358%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [8] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%A6846%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
>  [9] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C5268%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
> [10] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%A4433%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"
> ```

Then you could loop through and execute those statements 1 at a time. Alternately, you could put all of the results in 1 SQL statement using an "OR" keyword between each result, depending on what you need.

**Update**

You mentioned that instead of replacing a keyword in the string you wanted to use a variable:

```
query.part1 <- "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%" 
query.part2 <- "%' AND TYPE_GB ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"

paste0(query.part1, random_box, query.part2)
```

and here it is all in 1 statement:

```
value <- capture.output(cat(paste0(random_box, "%' OR '%")))

all.in.one <- paste0(query.part1, 
                     value, 
                     query.part2)

gsub("OR '%%'", "", all.in.one)
```

> [1] "SELECT FUND_CD, FUND_FNM FROM A001 WHERE FUND_CD LIKE '%C1866%'
>   OR '% A3236%' OR '% C8977%' OR '% A735%' OR '% C2102%' OR '% A3169%'
>   OR '% C2358%' OR '% A6846%' OR '% C5268%' OR '% A4433%'  AND TYPE_GB
>   ='A2' AND END_YMD = '99999999'"

Depending on the specific type of SQL (T-SQL, MySQL, etc) you may need to make some trivial adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm sure It would be great help. but I have a question. Isn't there way to just pass the variable in the SQL statement.?

Comment: @user13232877 Yes, if you want to use a variable instead of just replacing a keyword with `gsub` you can use `paste0`. I'm not sure that offers any improvement, but it's an option. I can include it as an example.

Comment: And dice explanation is just metaphor. in the document, it has a string, that is document name. So my ultimate goal is I want to search DB with this name. And everyday I have to deal with at least 70 document. so it is really hard to type directly or use sub function for it. This is my reason that I asked you just how to pass the variable. because if it is possible, I just put the variable 'box' in just one line statement. 'FUND_CD LIKE box'

Comment: @user13232877 I have now added examples of both how to do the same thing by breaking the sentence into 2 parts with a variable in the middle instead of just replacing a keyword (for whatever reason) and also how to do it all in 1 statement using `OR` and `paste0` as previously mentioned. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Awesome. I am really surprised with the result. Thank you sincerely, It works really well